# Reading from a slice of unknown length in Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to replicate this algorithm for finding duplicates in an array in Golang. Here's the javascript version:

```js
function hasDuplicateValue(array) {
  let existingNumbers = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(existingNumbers[array[i]] === 1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      existingNumbers[array[i]] = 1;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

On `line 2`, the algorithm creates an empty array of unknown length, and then adds `1` to an index in the array corresponding with each number that it finds (e.g. if it finds the number `3` in the array, it will add a `1` to index `3` in `existing numbers`.

I'm wondering — how do I replicate this in Golang (since we need to have slots allocated in the slice before reading it). Would I first need to find the max value in the array and then declare the `existingNumbers` slice to be of that same size?

Or is there a more efficient way of doing this (instead of searching through the array and finding the max value before constructing the slice).

Thanks!

**Edit:**
I realized that I can't do this with a `slice` because I can't read from an empty value. However, as @icza suggested, it will work with a map:

```golang
func findDuplicates(list []int)(bool) {
    temp := make(map[int]int)
    for _, elem := range list {
        if temp[elem] == 1 {
            return true
        } else {
            temp[elem] = 1
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Use a set for `existingNumbers`. There is no builtin set in Go, but a map will do just fine.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show your code? What problem did you run into? What you're describing sounds relatively straightforward and is described thoroughly in the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/).

Comment: @icza Ah yes, a map will work for this. Updated the question to show my solution. 

So is it impossible to do this efficiently using either slices or arrays? I have to use a map right (since the required length of the existingNumbers array is unknown from the outset)?

Comment: You have to (should) use a map to quickly tell if a number has been seen before (maps offer O(1) lookup). You could use a slice, and append new elements to it, that's perfectly normal, but you can't quickly tell if a number is in it, not without looping over all its elements.

Comment: @bugsyb, you can do this just as efficiently in Go as any other language, the logical constrains here have nothing to do with the language itself. For slice allocation, you can pre-allocate some or all of the max possible size, re-allocate as needed, or use a different data structure, but the same logic always applies. The javascript version just hides the implementation details from you.

Answer (score 0):

As comments, I would also suggest using a map to keep the state of the duplications, but we can use `map[int]struct{}` because empty structs are not consumed any memory in Go.

And also I have simplified the code a bit and it is as follows.

```
func findDuplicates(list []int) bool {
    temp := make(map[int]struct{})
    for _, elem := range list {
        if _, ok := temp[elem]; ok {
            return true
        }
        temp[elem] = struct{}{}
    }
    return false
}
```

Full code can be executed [here](https://go.dev/play/p/PytD-Qh0vv2)